# How to programmatically set drawableRight on Android Edittext?

Tags: android, drawable

I know about set drawableRight in XML. but i required to do it programmatically because it is change as per some condition.

Comment: Use **setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()** for EditText.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

You can use the function below:

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.drawableRight, 0);
```

or (if you want to pass the drawable itself instead of its ID)

```kotlin
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.drawableRight), null)
```

The order of params corresponding to the drawable location is: left, top, right, bottom

Comment: how can I assign an ID to that drawable ? basically I want to add a touch listener to that specific drawable

Comment: @Lawrence Choy hi sir,how to check Image is already exit or not.Please help me in this case,And how to change image color.

Answer (score 10):

Find Further [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

```
EditText myEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);
myEdit.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.icon, 0);  
// where params are (left,top,right,bottom)
```

You can also set drawable padding programmatically:

```
myEdit.setCompoundDrawablePadding("Padding value");
```

Comment: hi sir,how to check Image is already exit or not.Please help me in this case,And how to change image color

Answer (score 4):

Try like below:

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.smiley );
EdtText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0, 0, img, 0);
```

Edit :

```
 int img = R.drawable.smiley;
 EdtText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0, 0, img, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
EditText editFirstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_fname);
Drawable icUser = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_user);
editFirstname.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, icUser, null);
```

Then you can add a touch listener to that specific drawable.

Answer (score 3):

For changing left and right both at a time I use this single line.

```
download.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.ic_lock_open_white_24dp, 0, R.drawable.ic_lock_open_white_24dp, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int img = R.drawable.smiley;
editText.setCompoundDrawables( null, null, img, null );
```

Explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear to the left of, above, to the right of, and below the text. Use 0 if you do not want a Drawable there. The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds.

Answer (score 2):

```
        et_feedback.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {

                }
              et_feedback.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.mipmap.feedback_new, 0, 0);                
               et_feedback.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            }
        });
```

**Hide Drawable using this**

```
et_feedback.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

If it requires android graphics drawable then this will work

```
Drawable dw = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit);
Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
start.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(dw, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your editText view (here it is txview) built in function setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds() to do what you are looking for

in my code I Used it like this .
txview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_up,0);

```
txview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left,top,right,bottom);
```

Comment: You should explain your code to help the OP why it answers his question.

Answer (score 0):

From XML layout use the belows line

```
  android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_promocode"
```

From Kotlin or Java File

```
 etPromoCode.setStartDrawable(R.drawable.ic_promocode)
```

Done.☻♥ keep code.