# android textview drawableright programmatically

Tags: android, textview

How to make the drawableright image on textview to appear and disappear programmatically in android.  I have a textview and a button. When user press the button, it suppose to use the data on the textview to do something. However, if textview is empty, I want to show an error icon on the drawableright. Please advise.

Comment: Check for answer before asking question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297073/how-to-programatically-set-drawableright-on-android-edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError(java.lang.CharSequence)

Basically it will show a default error icon on the right inside the textview if you set it.