# How to embed icon inside textfield in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, compound-drawables

I am trying to implement a password field with an eye icon inside of it.
I am using `<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>` for animation purposes.

The eye icon however keeps on displaying under the EditText.

Here is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_login_password_visibility"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fragment_login_password"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_show_password" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297073/how-to-programatically-set-drawableright-on-android-edittext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_show_password"` to your EditText.
And get rid of the ImageView.

You can use compound drawables to put an icon to the left (as in my example), to the right, top and/or bottom of a View.

Comment: Now the icon is **inside** your View, instead of being **outside** of it. ;)

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot!