# How to find Image from raw folder inside res

Tags: android

I have four Images Google, Yahoo, GMail and I want if someone input in edit text Google then set imageview of Google.

For this I have made a raw folder inside res folder containing all the images and as someone input in edit text it is contained in String s (like s="Google") but I don't know how further set image

Comment: You should put your images in the drawable folders.

Comment: `raw` folder is for medias; use `mipmap` for launcher icons and use `drawable` for other images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programatically set drawableRight on Android Edittext?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297073/how-to-programatically-set-drawableright-on-android-edittext)

Answer (score -1):

You can get Image as InputStream via this way

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier("image name",
            "raw", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: Sir, How can I get multiple images by input stream like if user select both Yahoo and Google. Basically I am making a grid view of image and name so how can I get multiple images

Comment: Add selected variable to arraylist and do what you need with forloop.

Answer (score -1):

```
 int identifier = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("file_name","raw", mContext.getPackageName());
    if(identifier>0){
        imageView.setImageResource(identifier);
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with `R.raw.image_name`? Looking up a resource name is slow

Comment: Please don't write only code, explain it, so the OP can learn from your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Load you image from raw folder like this :

```
if(etText.equals("Google")    {
    InputStream imageIS = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.google);
}
else if(etText.equals("Yahoo")    {
    InputStream imageIS = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yahoo);
}
else if(etText.equals("GMail")    {
    InputStream imageIS = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.gmail);
}

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageIS);
```

and then load it in your imageview as :

```
 imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int imageArray[] = {R.drawable.google, R.drawable.yahoo, R.drawable.gmail};

//onClick
String etStr = edittext.getText().toString();

if(etStr.equals("Google"){
     imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[0]);
}else if(etStr.equals("Yahoo"){
     imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[1]);
}else if(etStr.equals("GMail"){
     imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[2]);
}
```